# Identify frame within the structure of an object in QTP

Tags: qtp

I am working with `QTP11` on Web based `AUT`. I have objects in my OR. Most objects are in frames. The way `AUT` works is that every time a page is rendered, the `HTML ID` of the frame changes (which is the only property we can use to identify the frame). This is not a problem because I am dynamically updating the `HTML ID` of the frame every time we get to a page. Objects are generally in this format:

```
Browser>Page>Frame>WebElement> and then the object
```

I'm getting the GrandParent of the object (and then checking if its a Frame class) to identify the position of the frame. This wont always work as there are object that have a different structure. Is there a more efficient way to identify where the frame object is in the structure other than just going up the tree?

Comment: Care to share the code you use in order to _get the GrandParent_?

Comment: @Motti. I apologies if this isn't the correct way to reply to your post but its my first time doing this. Yeah no worries.

Comment: 'Set objParent = objQTPClass.GetTOProperty("parent")'    This gives me the Parent and then I use the same to get GrandParent    'Set objGrandParent = objParent .GetTOProperty("parent")'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hard-coding the number of levels you go up in the hierarchy to 2 (grand-parent) you can keep climbing until you reach an object of type `Frame`.

Something like:

```vbs
Public Function GetAncestorOfType(ByRef testObj, ByRef name)
       While testObj.GetTOPRoperty("micclass") <> name
          Set testObj = testObj.GetTOProperty("parent")
       Wend
       Set GetAncestorOfType = testObj
End Function

' Usage:
Set frameObj = GetAncestorOfType(obj, "Frame")
```

Comment: Thanks, that's brilliant. Not sure how to accept this as an answer though. Can you please advice how I can do that? Thanks

Comment: @Zac, I see you figured out how to accept the answer :)

Comment: :) Yes thanks .. had a brain freeze moment but I think its back in gear now